# Authentication failed when trying to connect to mlab

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, mean-stack

I know this issue has been handled before, but I don't believe those solutions are working for me.

I am following https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4 tutorial, to quickly setup a backend for project.

However, each time I try to connect mongdb throws an error, saying authentication failed.

Now, I tried doing:

```
mongo ds159670.mlab.com:59670/budget -u myUser -p myPassword
```

with the correct user and password, but it tells me my version is higher than the server version, and then it does nothing.

I'm at a loss.

Server.js excerpt

// config files
//var db = require('./config/db');

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<correctuser>:<correctpassword>@ds159670.mlab.com:59670/budget'); // connect to our database

var Budget   = require('./models/budget');
```

There is no quotation mark in the correctuser and correctpassword.

UPDATE:
So it seems the version is not the problem (for now), but rather, it just hangs on connection to:. And then it does nothing. Is there any certain thing I need to do? I am on a Windows 10 machine, at home.

Comment: Which user and password are you using to authenticate? If it is your `mlab` account user and password it is no going to work. You need to create a `Database user`.

Comment: Hey!

It is the database user, I am trying to connect to, unfortunately. Thanks though! :D